# Array sorting algorithm for different destinations

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to resolve this issue but no luck.

Question is - I have an array for different locations.

For example:

```
   Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [from] => Paris
        [to] => Marseille
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [from] => Marseille
        [to] => Valencia
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [from] => Valencia
        [to] => Algiers
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [from] => Algiers
        [to] => Abu Dhabi
    )

)
```

No matter what order i give it should always return next destination "From" where it ends.

Array to be sorted so that the `from` keys continue from the `to` key of the previous array.

For example if my from location is "Paris" and To location "Marseille" then the next array order should be From "Marseille" and To "Valencia" and again next array From should be "Valencia" and to "New location".

I don't believe if there is any built-in function available.

Comment: It's a one multi dimension array.

Comment: So you want a multi-dimensional array to be sorted so that the `from` keys continue from the `to` key of the previous array?

Comment: Yes correct! I have updated my question...

Comment: Which means that the sort routine must know your start point, which is?

Comment: Is every sub-array guaranteed to always have a corresponding array which it can be tied to? Would you ever have `[4] => Array ( [from] => New York [to] => San Francisco)` in addition to your example?

Comment: Would you ever have `[4] => Array ( [from] => Paris [to] => Valencia)` in addition to your example?

Comment: No I can't be, sub array guaranteed to always have corresponding array.

Comment: @Mark Baker  if `from` key has not been used in `to` key it will always be the first element of array.

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't mean to gloat but [check out my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37141173/2191572) :)

Comment: It's not exactly the travelling salesman problem, but somewhat closely related to it. And that's a *hard problem*. Some more context would help here, like scenarios in which this needs to work and other limitations and requirements which it must fulfil...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there are no breaks in the chain (or loops), then the following function should build a sorted route:

```
$from = array_column($route, 'from');
$to = array_column($route, 'to');
$start = array_diff($from, $to);

$sortedRoute = [$route[key($start)]];
$start = $route[key($start)]['to'];
while (true) {
    $key = array_search($start, $from);
    if ($key === false)
        break;
    $sortedRoute[] = $route[$key];
    $start = $route[$key]['to'];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/b6UiZ)

There will be more efficient ways of doing this, and ways in which the basic algorithm can be optimised e.g. by flipping $from so that it could be accessed directly by key rather than using array_search(); but as a basic router, it works

Comment: Short answer! That's exactly i've been looking for! +1 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which will sort your multi-dimensional array:

```
<?php
function sort_travel_plans($a)
{
    $return = [];

    $count_a = count($a);

    while(count($return) !== $count_a)
    {
        foreach($a as $k=>$v)
        {
            $add_where = null;

            if($return)
            {
                foreach($return as $k2=>$v2)
                {
                    if($v['to'] === $v2['from'])
                    {
                        $add_where = 'before';
                    }
                    elseif($v['from'] === $v2['to'])
                    {
                        $add_where = 'after';
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $add_where = 'after';
            }

            if($add_where === 'before')
            {
                array_unshift($return, $v);
                unset($a[$k]);
            }
            elseif($add_where === 'after')
            {
                $return[] = $v;
                unset($a[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    unset($a, $add_where, $count_a, $v, $v2);

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few prerequisites to keep in mind,

- The starting point should be given.
- There shouldn't be two branches possible, though if the user is visiting the same place twice then you can append '2' something like that.
- If a dead end is met before the whole array is processed then the function will return the array until it met the dead end. Or maybe we can just compare the no of elements inside the input and output arrays and return output if they match or false if they dont.

Something along the lines...

```
function sortdestinations($input_array, $current_location = null) {
    if (!is_array($input_array) || empty($input_array)) {
        return false;  // empty array or non-array element passed.
    }
    if (!$current_location || empty($current_location)) {
        return false;  // empty start location given
    }
    // Actual beginning of the logic
    $output = array();
    while (count($input_array)) {
        $nextlocation_found = 0;
        foreach ($input_array as $key => $location) {
            if ($location['from'] == $current_location) {
                $output[] = $location; // storing the location
                $current_location = $location['to'];
                unset($input_array[$key]);
                $nextlocation_found = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!$nextlocation_found) {
            return $output;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$input_array = array(
    array(
        'from' => 'Paris',
        'to' => 'Marseille'
    ),
    array(
        'from' => 'Marseille',
        'to' => 'Valencia'
    ),
    array(
        'from' => 'Valencia',
        'to' => 'Algiers'
    ),
    array(
        'from' => 'Algiers',
        'to' => 'Abu Dhabi'
    )
);
shuffle($input_array); // randomizing the array each time it is being processed, just for testing. 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($input_array);
echo "</pre>";

$finalout = sortdestinations($input_array, 'Paris');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($finalout); // var_dump to show even if false is returned :)
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/pkCyVkAf)**

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution is far less elegant than others, but here it is nonetheless:

```
function agenda_sort($inArray) {

    // set up sorted array
    $outArray = null;

    //prepare list of cities
    for ($i=0; $i<count($inArray); $i++) {
        $froms[] = $inArray[$i]['from'];
        $tos[] = $inArray[$i]['to'];
    }

    // find the origination city; it should only exist in first array
    $origin = (array_diff($froms, $tos));

    //find origin in first array; push that pair to new array
    for ($i=0; $i<count($inArray); $i++) {
        if ($inArray[$i]['from'] == $origin[0]) {
            $outArray[] = $inArray[$i];
        }

    }


    $c = 0;

    // loop through array and add appropriate city based on to/from comparison
    while (count($outArray) < count($inArray)) {

        for ($i=0; $i<count($inArray); $i++) {
            if ($inArray[$i]['from'] ==$outArray[$c]['to']) {
                $outArray[$i] = $inArray[$c];
            }
        }
    $c++;
    }

    return $outArray;
}
```